# Django custom FileField attribute and property

Tags: django

I want to add a property to the FileField, so that I can specify when adding a field to the model.

```
class TestFile(models.Model):
    c206 = CategoryFileField(
        category='206'
    )
```

And also get the same value from the model instance.

```
tf = TestFile.objects.latest('id')
tf.c206.category # 206
```

I tried to extend FileFiled by analogy with ImageFileField:

```
class CategoryMetadataMixin(object):
    @property
    def category(self):
        return self.category


class CategoryFieldFile(CategoryMetadataMixin, FieldFile):
    pass


class CategoryFileField(FileField):
    attr_class = CategoryFieldFile
    descriptor_class = FileDescriptor
    description = _("File")

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, category='', **kwargs):
        self.attr_class.category = category
        super().__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if self.category:
            kwargs['category'] = self.category
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

But in this case `category` always returns `''`. Apparently I went the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Today with a clear mind I studied the sources more closely. In the end, it turned out:

```
class CategoryFieldFile(FieldFile):
    @property
    def category(self):
        return self.field.category

    @category.setter
    def category(self, value):
        self.field.category = value


class CategoryFileField(FileField):
    attr_class = CategoryFieldFile
    descriptor_class = FileDescriptor
    description = _("File")

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, category='', **kwargs):
        self.category = category
        super().__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if self.category:
            kwargs['category'] = self.category
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

It works.